# Dual boot openSUSE and Windows 8.1 on two separate PCIe SSDs

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, multi-boot, uefi, opensuse

I have an X99 system with an Intel SSD 750 serving as the boot drive. Currently only Windows 8.1 is installed on it. My motherboard has an M.2 slot that I would like to use for a Samsung SM951 for an openSUSE install. My question is can I use the boot loader to switch between these two at boot time? Or will the fact that they are PCIe drives mess up the process? I suppose I could just choose which drive to boot to from the EFI shell each time. But I want to see if anyone has done this first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is can I use the boot loader to switch between these two at boot time?

You definitely can, if you are referring to GRUB2. Windows, of course, only wants to boot itself. [This Ubuntu page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) even shows you how to preserve the original bootloader, so that, should you wish to remove the  disk on which you installed OpenSUSE, there will be nothing for you to do to have a working, Windows-only installation.

It basically says:

> On a system with multiple drives and OS's, the user can preserve the original bootloader by installing GRUB 2 on another drive. To accomplish this:
>
> specify the disk (eg /dev/sdX, not /dev/sdaXY) not currently used to boot the system for the bootloader location.
>
> After the installation is complete, change the boot order (via BIOS setup) so that the disk to which the GRUB information was written is the one booted first.
>
> If the user wishes to restore booting with the original bootloader, change the boot order back to the original drive.

It is very important that you check the order in which the BIOS searches the disks for a bootloader: [this UNIX/Linux stack exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66895/grub-with-two-hard-drives) will show the pitfalls (and the solution to the pitfalls) of not checking this.

Comment: Ok great! I wasn't sure if some combination of these being PCIe and NVMe drives on a UEFI system with secure boot would throw a wrench in things. Thank you!